# measure of unbounded part goes to zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We have the result that :for a measureable function $f$ , $\mu\{x:|f(x)|>k\} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ if $\mu(X) < \infty$. We can prove it by continuous of measure.

My question is why the intersection of set $\bigcap_k\{x:|f(x)|>k\}$ is empty. It's possible that $f(x) = \infty$?

Comment: It is up to you whether you are studying functions that take the value $\infty$ or not at some point. You could even have the function $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in X$, in which case $\mu\{x:|f(x)|>k\}=\mu(X)$ doesn't tend to zero. So, some conditions must be imposed on $f$. Which conditions do you have?

Comment: I got it, thanks.It's a exercise problem that needs to prove $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$ in measure with $\mu(X) <\infty$ then  also $f_ng_n\to fg$ .No addtional condition on it.

Comment: For example, if $f$ only takes values $<\infty$, then $\bigcap _k \{x:|f(x)|>k\}=\emptyset$. If $\mu(X)<\infty$ it follows that $\mu\{x:|f(x)|>k\}\to0$.